# Avoid Byte Code injection Java

Tags: tomcat, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation, appserver

I am currently using javassist to manipulate byte code at runtime for my appserver.
I am not creating methods or changing prototype nor creating additional member variables.
Are there any security policies or any other ways to block runtime byte code manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

The user obviously has final control over which code they run on their machine. If you don't want people to run an altered version of your code on your server, don't give them access to your server.

Comment: Yeah that is obvious. But I want to know are there any ways to control byte code manipulations through enabling security manager or some parameters to JVM.

Comment: @SainathSarma What is your attack model? It's hard to tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am working on a project for app servers like Tomcat, where end users can add loggers on the fly to debug their issues. 
So I just want to check are there any ways to disable Instrumentation which is a counteract to this project.

Comment: What's the problem with users debugging their own server?